# Instantly update fields of forms - Django

Tags: html, django, django-forms, calculator, financialinstrument

I am still on the way to learning Django.
I am going to create an app. That would essentially be an instant financial ratios calculator. Which would comprise of various forms (say like Loan calculations, Mortgage calculations, interest calculations, etc, etc. one field from one form(Loan calculator) would also be part of other single or multiple forms. The target (field on another form) will need to be instantly updated as the user is updating the inputs on the form
Using the typical approach of forms and views (that will essentially bind to HTTP [get/post]).
I am looking for a way to have the field (derived from one field) updated instantly as soon as an input is received from the user.
The basic example is here

https://html.form.guide/calculation-forms/simple-html-calculation-form/

I am keen to use Django, what do you guys suggest would be the best approach to undertaking the above-mentioned tasks and at the same time satisfying the instant field update criterion as in the link above?

Looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The task you mentioned is more like frontend stuff. You should use javascript.